# Change RPi to 32 bit architecture

Tags: terminal

While attempting to install Wine on my RPi, I changed the architecture to 32 bit. I used the command, `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`, but I don't know how to change back to 64 bit. Does anyone know the command?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following will remove the architecture you just added:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
```

However, there's something important to note here. The `i386` architecture generally refers to 32-bit processors based on the [IA-32 architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IA-32). i386 is compatible with the vast majority of desktops and laptops, **but not your Pi**. The Pi uses an [ARM processor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) which is not compatible with i386.

Any program compiled for i386 simply cannot be 'understood' by ARM processors and so cannot run. Running Wine won't work on a Pi because Windows is an x86 operating system with x86 programs, and they can't be run on a Pi.

While the Pi 3 does have a 64-bit processor, the operating systems such as Raspbian [are still 32-bit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/61785/58316) so you can't really "change back to 64-bit"... since you were never there! The architecture for 64-bit ARM processors is, rather unimaginatively, `arm64`, but the default for Raspbian is the 32-bit `armhf` (at least according to `dpkg --print-architecture`).

Comment: Basically WINE (Wine Is Not and Emulator) doesn't emulate the machine code. It is designed to work on an i386 platform (either 32 or 64 bits). It just intercepts some library and BIOS calls to make a program think it is running on a Windows platform. Running it on a Raspberry Pi will not work. You'll have to find an emulator.